# How can you determine the ConfigurationBuild type for a TFSBuild?

Tags: configuration, tfsbuild

I have Debug|Any CPU and Release|Any CPU as my two configuration types. Is there any way I can tell the TFSBuild which one to 'build'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Undocumented switch [msBuildArguments](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/22f31fc5-1456-4ae4-898b-b43c5e444cc7):

```
TFSBuild.exe start /queue %TFSSVR% %TEAMPROJECT% %BUILDTYPE% /msBuildArguments:"/p:Configuration=Debug"
```

Or documented text file with name TFSBuild.rsp  near your build script and with content:

```
/p:Configuration=Debug
```

EDIT:
each line can have one /p:XXXXX build argument.